# VideoView works badly

Tags: java, android, uri, android-videoview

When I try to play video from my app while debugging it on my phone, Android system communicate appears which says "Can't play this video". I don't know what is going on. I searched stackoverflow for this but I've only found answers for playing videos placed in raw folder, but I want it to play from web and to do not use WebView to do so. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String filmkey;
    VideoView ekran;
    WebView screen;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       filmkey = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZJalBmtGnQ";

        VideoView ekran = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(filmkey);
        ekran.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        ekran.setVideoURI(video);
        ekran.start();
        ekran.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permission in `Manifests`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I am not sure whether you can play youtube video with `VideoView`. Your code works fine for non youtube video.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        String filmkey;
        VideoView ekran;
        WebView screen;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            filmkey = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

            VideoView ekran = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(filmkey);
            ekran.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            ekran.setVideoURI(video);
            ekran.start();
            ekran.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try this. You have to use youtube API for playing youtube videos.

Comment: Try this [Tutorial on the link](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/play-youtube-android-youtube-player-api/#.WYoRd8iCzIU) to use youtube API

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `YouTube` URL to `VideoView`. `VideoView` can play **video only URLs** eg. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp (given in @H.M answer),

Think how `VideoView` can play URL which is of the whole page? You can play Youtube Videos with **RTSP** URL of specific video provided by youtube. Check this post for more detail on [playing YouTube Videos in Android](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/).